# Php Pagination while passing Query String

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

In Php,while passing query string from page to another page how to do pagination.The following code I used it works fine for pagination without query string but while passing value from page to another page(Query String) it dint work.
Please give me any suggestions.

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$adjacents = 3;
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM data";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

$targetpage = "pagetest.php";
$limit = 10;
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page)
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
else
    $start = 0;

$sql = "SELECT name,email,dateins FROM data WHERE name='$id' LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$cnt=0;

                  if($result)
                  while($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                  {
                  $cnt=$cnt+1;
                  $cssRow="class='gridRow'";
                  if(($cnt%2)==1)
                  {
                     $cssRow="class='gridRowAlternate'";
                  }

if ($page == 0) $page = 1;
$prev = $page - 1;                          
$next = $page + 1;                          
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      


$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";

    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=$prev\">Previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">Previous</span>";   

    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                  
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    
    {
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                  
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";        
        }
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                  
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";        
        }
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                  
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=$next\">Next</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">Next</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";
    }
    ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rs['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rs['email']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rs['dateins']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
          }
          ?>
 <td><input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
 </table>
 <?php echo $pagination; ?>
 ?>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: What error did you get while using passing through query string?

Comment: I am not getting any error.In first page it displays the data while in second page it is not displaying any data.

Comment: Show your generated query, when you go to second page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the $_GET variables that you want to see to the links in your pagination otherwise after the first request you will not be able to use them.

For example:

```
  if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id&page=$prev&something=$_GET['something']\">Previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">Previous</span>";
```

I also noticed your $_GET variables are set wrong in your links.

This

```
<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>
```

should be

```
<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$id&page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>
```

It might be easier to add any other variables to a session so you dont need to worry about dymanically adding them to the query string if there are more than one.

Answer (score 0):

**Page:- pagination.func.inc.php**

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul.pagination {

        font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        height:auto;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 20px 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0; 

    }
    ul.pagination li.details {

        background-color: white;
        border-color: #C8D5E0;
        border-image: none;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px 1px 2px;
        color: #1E598E;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 6px 10px;
        text-decoration: none; 

    }
    ul.pagination li.dot {

        padding: 3px 0; 

    }
    ul.pagination li {

        float: left;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 3px 0 0; 

    }
    ul.pagination li:first-child {

        margin-left: 0; 

    }
    ul.pagination li a {

        color: black;
        display: block;
        line-height:normal;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        text-decoration: none; 

    }
    ul.pagination li a img {

        border: medium none; 

    }
    ul.pagination li a.current {

        background-color:#08569D;
        color:#fff;

    }
    ul.pagination li a.current:hover {

        /*background-color: white;
        color: #333333; */

    }
    ul.pagination li a:hover {

        /*background-color: #C8D5E0; */
        background-color:#08569D;
        color:#fff;

    }
    ul.pagination li a {

        background-color: #F6F6F6;
        border-color: #C8D5E0;
        border-image: none;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px ;
        color: #1E598E;
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        text-decoration: none; 

    }
    ul.pagination li.details {
        border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
        color: #999999;
    }
    </style> 
    <?php

    function pagination_function($per_page = 10, $page = 1, $url = '', $total)
    {

        $adjacents = "2";

        $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

        $prev = $page - 1;
        $next = $page + 1;
        $firstpage = 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {
            $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
            //$pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
            if($page == '1')
            {
                $pagination .= "<li class='details'>First</li>";
                $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Previous</li>";
            }
            else
            {   
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$firstpage'>First</a></li>";
                $pagination .= "<li><a href='{$url}$prev'>Previous</a></li>";
            }

            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";
                }
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($page < $counter - 1){
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$next'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
            }else{
                $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Next</li>";
                $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Last</li>";
                //$pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
                // $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
            }
            $pagination.= "</ul>\n";
        }
        return $pagination;
    }

    ?>
```

**Your page**

```
<?php
        include("connect.php");
        require_once('pagination.func.inc.php');
        $id = $_REQUEST["id"];

        $pageno = addslashes(trim($_REQUEST['page']));
        if($pageno !=''){$pageno = $pageno;}else{$pageno = '1';}

        //Your Query
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM data";
        $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

        $total_pages = $total_pages[num]; // Total Record
        $targetpage = "pagetest.php";
        $limit = 10; // Par page limit

        //Here your While/Foorlop/foreach condition

        $get_pageurl = $targetpage ."?page=";
        echo $pagination_function = pagination_function($limit,$pageno,$get_pageurl,$total_pages);
        ?>
```